# C# How can I set different proxy server for each connection?

Tags: c#, websocket, websocket-sharp

I am coding a client in C# that communicates with my webserver with web sockets but I want each connection from the client to come from proxy IP, how can I do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: @Codexer I use websocket-sharp library to connect to my web server but I want each connection to come from proxy server.